# phalcon php model not created in ubutu 20.04 with nginx with phalocn model model_name

Tags: nginx, model-view-controller, phalcon

i am using ubuntu-20.04 focal fossa. my Phalcon dev-tool version is 4.1 and phalcon version is 3.4.5 when i create model inside project it's not working following details shown as attchemnt.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FobMT.png)

Comment: Please post the error as text not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra ok